# add Linked List into Double Linked List ( java ) ?

Tags: java, linked-list

i have project in university . And in this project want to do like google or yahoo. I have many word,  i should insert the word to double linked list and inside double linked list another linked list . I don't know how to add linkdlist into double linked list . So, if anyone can help me , Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Can you not use `LinkedList<String>` or another List? Or are you trying to add a `List<String>` to a `List<List<String>>`?

Comment: The university wants me do this.

I can use LinkedList<String> , But i don't know the method to do that !

Just i want the idea , and I'm going to write it my way .

Comment: You either want to add it to a `List<String>` in which case use `addAll` or you have a `List<List<String>>` in which case you need `add`. I suspect there is a deeper problem but I don't know what it is.

Comment: i have folder , inside the folder Files, inside the files word .

i want create double LinkedList ,  inside it word and LinkedList , inside Linked List files . The files mean that have same word in double Linked List .

i hope is my idea is clear to you .

Comment: You can scan all the files in the folder and read each file as words and combine these as list of list of words. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeeeeeees .  Now How to store them in a suitable data structure (a linked list) ?

Comment: Like I said, you use `add()` to add them as it says in the documentation.  I suspect you need to do some research so you will have a better understanding of the answers to your questions. I suggest you read up on how to use Scanner on a file to break it into words and how to use Lists. (I suspect ArrayList is a better choice for you)

Comment: Thank you sooooo much Peter , Sorry i took from your time many . :)

Comment: No problem, everyone has to start somewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new structure A that contains a Word property and a LinkedList of A property.

In your main app, work with a DoubleLinkedList of A